# Spring Boot Session handling

Tags: spring-mvc, session, spring-boot

How does Spring Boot handles sessions for a rest service? I know there has to be something integrated, but I don't really understand how it works for me.

Currently I've a custom session object which store the person object and a generated ID (written by my own). And of course I made a own controller...

Is there a nice way to receive on every call a session object or do I have to write it to every call on my own?

Comment: A RESTful architecture is supposed to store very little amount of information (if any) in a server session. What do you want to use it for? Authentication tokens? Also keep in mind that boot uses Spring MVC for managing web requests, so refer to it in the question.

Comment: yes I use it for authentication tokens; I store only the ID and the object

Comment: Then just add spring security integration and let it manage your user sessions. You'll be able to access the logged user and his permissios from anywhere in your code.

Comment: is there a good tutorial for that? I didn't find anything like that (in a style like I want)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) or [Spring Session](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/) in order to have a Session Management in your boot project. Spring session is a rather new project that provides the following features:

- API and implementations for managing a user's session
- **HttpSession** - allows replacing the HttpSession in an application
  container (i.e. Tomcat) neutral way

  - Clustered Sessions - Spring Session makes it trivial to support clustered sessions without being tied to an application container   specific solution.
  - Multiple Browser Sessions - Spring Session supports managing multiple users' sessions in a single browser instance (i.e. multiple authenticated accounts similar to Google).
  - RESTful APIs - Spring Session allows providing session ids in headers to work with RESTful APIs
- WebSocket - provides the ability to keep the HttpSession alive when
  receiving WebSocket messages